# What are portability of backup, remote backup and networked backup mean?

Tags: backup

From the book [Linux Administration Made Easy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/server-backup.html):

1. > When deciding on a backup solution, you will need to consider the
   >   following factors:
   >
   > **Portability** − Is backup portability (ie. the ability to backup on one Linux distribution or implementation of Unix and restore to
   >   another; for example from Solaris to Red Hat Linux) important to you?
   >   If so, you'll probably want to choose one of the command−line tools
   >   (eg. `dd`, `dump`, `cpio`, or `tar`), because you can be reasonably
   >   sure that such tools will be available on any *nix system.

   What does "backup on one Linux distribution or implementation of
   Unix and restore to another" mean? Is it to backup a Linux system
   and then restore it later? Then what does it mean by "restore to
   another"?
2. > **Remote backups** − Is the ability to start backups and restores from a remote machine important to you? If so, you'll probably want
   >   to
   >   choose one of the command−line tools or text−based utilities instead
   >   of the GUI−based utilities (unless you have a reasonably fast network
   >   connection and the ability to run remote X sessions).
   >
   > **Network backups** − Is performing backups and restores to and from networked hosts important to you? If so, you'll probably want
   >   to use
   >   one of several of the command−line utilities (such as `tar`) which
   >   support network access to backup devices, or a specialized utility
   >   such as `Amanda` or one of several commercial utilities.

   It seems that remote backup and network backup are the same. What
   are their differences?

Answer (score 1):

Ah backups... Before portability...

The starting point for setting up a backup system is to determine what you're trying to accomplish with the backup.

For example, even a simple WordPress backup requires making a copy of both the database + flat files associated with the WordPress install.

If the system is more complex, meaning for example there are custom changes to apache's configuration (if apache is in use), then /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd must also be added to the backup.

So the real starting point of a backup system is to consider when + how the backup will be used, when site moves to another machine because the site requires more resources or there is a catastrophic hardware failure.

My rule of thumb is, "you only have a backup, if you can create a running system from your backup in a few minutes."

Otherwise you just have a pile of files + hours/days of work.

Once you know how you'll use your backup, then you can consider what you use for your final archive file - zip or xz or bzip2 - and the good news is, so long as your going linux to linux you can use just about anything.

If you're going between many operating systems, use zip as zip/unzip are pretty much every where, even "Windoze".